# Silent install of vcredist_xxx.exe

Tags: windows, powershell, silent-installer, vcredist

I have successfully installed vcredist_x86.exe and vcredist_x64.exe on Windows Server 2008R2, 2012 and 2012R2 using:

```
start-process -FilePath "vcredist_x86.exe" -ArgumentList "/install /q /norestart" -Verb RunAs -wait
```

**BUT**

For some reason this does not work on 2008 (NOT R2), neither x86 or x64. I always get prompted. The file is being installed from a \share.

Help is much appriciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a theory but what are the PowerShell versions of some of these systems? I wonder if they dont support the verb.

Comment: W2008 64bit:
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1

2008R2
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1

Seems to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-wait parameter does not work with 2012 vcredist in W2008.